# How to put elements of a file into a hash? -Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

So I have a file in the form of:

```
Key1   Value1
Key2   Value2
Key3   Value3
```

seperated by a tab. My question is how do I open this file and put it into a hash? I have tried to do:

```
 fp = File.open(file_path)

 fp.each do |line|
   value = line.chomp.split("\t")
   hash = Hash[*value.flatten]
 end
```

But at the end of this loop the @datafile hash only contains the latest entry...I kinda want it all.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hash[key] = value` to add a new key-value pair. `hash.update(otherhash)` to add the key-value-pairs from otherhash to hash.

If you do `hash = foo`, you reassign hash, losing the old contents.

So for your case, you can do:

```
hash = {}
File.open(file_path) do |fp|
  fp.each do |line|
    key, value = line.chomp.split("\t")
    hash[key] = value
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to instantiate hash (hash = {}) before the File.open block, or else it won't be available following the last end statement.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120285/2097284:

`hash = Hash[*File.read(file_path).split("\t")]`

This expands to

`hash = Hash["Key1", "Value1", "Key2", "Value2", "Key3", "Value3"]`.

For more robustness, replace `"\t"` with `/\s+/` (to allow any kind of whitespace).