# Using Ruby, Reading a file, containing name/value pairs into a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a file that has a name/value pair on each line, I want to open the file, read each line and initialize a hash.

file:

```
john, 234
joe, 2222
```

And load a hash so I can loop through the key value pairs.

Answer (score 23):

```
Hash[*File.read('f.txt').split(/[, \n]+/)]
```

Comment: Nice. And regexp can be even shorter: `/, |\n/`

Answer (score 10):

```
Hash[File.read('some.txt').split("\n").map{|i|i.split(', ')}]
```

or

```
Hash[File.read('some.txt').scan(/(.+?), (.+)/)]
```

Comment: that's a job security snippet! hehe

Comment: The scan is really useful here for a file that doesn't contain a consistent format.

Answer (score 6):

```
file_data = {}
File.open('some_file', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    line_data = line.split(',')
    file_data[line_data[0]] = line_data[1]
  end
end
```

You'll probably want to add some validation, but that is a simple way to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 6):

```
f = <<EOF
john, 234
joe, 2222
EOF

p Hash[*f.split(/, |\n/)]
```

The method #split gives an array looking like ["john,", "234", "joe,", "2222"]. The * (AKA splat) operator converts this array to a bunch of arguments. Hash#[] takes this bunch of arguments (when there are an even number of arguments) and delivers a hash.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: yeah, overlooked the trailing comma's. Added the regex.

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  Very useful for us Ruby foreigners making our way with tools like Rake & Buildr!