# Read file into hash with 2 values per key?

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

Very similar question to: [Using Ruby, Reading a file, containing name/value pairs into a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119763/using-ruby-reading-a-file-containing-name-value-pairs-into-a-hash)

file:

`server1, jim, 22
server2, bob, 44`

Tried this regular expression:

`Hash[*File.read('file.cfg').split(/[, \n]+/)]`

But I get:
`odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError)`

Me trying this out: http://rubular.com/r/BE6ZG2nTMw

What is the way to approach this? Is the issue the way the hash is initialized or my regexp?

Comment: is it a CSV?  does it have headers?

Comment: Not CSV, just a plain text file. `my_hash = Hash[*File.read('file.cfg').split(/[, \n]+/)]`

Comment: I doubt the result you are getting with your code is what you indeed want to get as a result.

Comment: what do you want the hash to look like?

Comment: Well @Anthony istarted with the assumption that I would need a hash similar to `{"server1"=>["jim", "22"], "server2"=>["bob","22"]}` but I'm not so sure an array would be simpler here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is the expected result:

```
File.readlines('/tmp/blah.cfg').map do |line|
  line.split(',', 2).map(&:strip)
end.to_h
#⇒ {"server1"=>"jim, 22", "server2"=>"bob, 44"}
```

One might also split the rest into an array:

```
File.readlines('/tmp/blah.cfg').map do |line|
  k, *v = line.split(',').map(&:strip)
  [k, v]
end.to_h
#⇒ {"server1"=>["jim", "22"], "server2"=>["bob", "44"]}
```

Comment: Let me try this real quick and verify.

Comment: Is this making a key=> then putting two things "john, 22" into one value? I believe the desired result woud be `{"server1"=>["jim", "22"], "server2"=>["bob","22"]}`