# How to iterate through a hash made of two arrays in Puppet and use both key and value in a module .pp file

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm new to Puppet ruby coding and I'm struggling trying to iterate through a hash so I can use both key and value in a .pp file in the module to create directories.

So far, I have two text files that contain the names of the directories to be created and the groups to be used to create them.

name_list.txt

```
john
mike
tom
```

group_list.txt

```
admins
users
tech
```

Both files are synced, so the first entry in names_list.txt has its counterpart in group_list.txt as the first entry as well. In this way I should be able later to create the following directories with these groups:

```
john -> admins
mike -> users
tom  -> tech
```

I access those files using two custom facts:

```
Facter.add('name_list') do
  setcode do
    if File.exist?("/tmp/name_list.txt")
      Array(File.readlines("/tmp/name_list.txt").map{|l| l.chomp})
    end
  end
end
```

```
Facter.add('group_list') do
  setcode do
    if File.exist?("/tmp/group_list.txt")
      Array(File.readlines("/tmp/group_list.txt").map{|l| l.chomp})
    end
  end
end
```

and combine them in another custom fact to create the hash:

```
Facter.add(:hash_list) do
  setcode do
    hash_list = {}
    Facter.value(:name_list).each do |dir_name|
      Facter.value(:group_list).each do |group_name|
        hash_list[dir_name] = group_name
      end
    end
    hash_list
  end
end
```

Finally, the code part in the manifest .pp file that should create the directories is this one:

```
$hash_list.each |$dir_name, $new_group| {
      file { "/tmp/${dir_name}":
        ensure => directory,
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => $new_group,
        mode   => '755',
      }
}
```

When I run puppet agent, I have the below error that shows that the iteration through the group_list is trying to use the last entry in the file only:

```
Error: Could not find group tech
Info: Unknown failure using insync_values? on type: File[/tmp/john] / property: group to compare values ["tech"] and 0
Error: /Stage[main]/Temp::Test/File[/tmp/john]/group: change from 'root' to 'tech' failed: Could not find group tech
Error: Could not find group tech
Info: Unknown failure using insync_values? on type: File[/tmp/mike] / property: group to compare values ["tech"] and 0
Error: /Stage[main]/Temp::Test/File[/tmp/mike]/group: change from 'root' to 'tech' failed: Could not find group tech
Error: Could not find group tech
Info: Unknown failure using insync_values? on type: File[/tmp/tom] / property: group to compare values ["tech"] and 0
Error: /Stage[main]/Temp::Test/File[/tmp/tom]/group: change from 'root' to 'tech' failed: Could not find group tech
```

The below shows that indeed the :hash_list hash is not returning the right group for every directory:

```
# puppet facts hash_list
{
  "hash_list": {
    "john": "tech",
    "mike": "tech",
    "tom": "tech"
  }
}
```

I have done lots of tests trying to correct it but I wasn't able to manage it due to my lack of experience in Ruby/Puppet code.

Can someone explain me how to do it properly?

**EDIT**

After John Bollinger's answer, I saw the need of make my question more clear and remake it. I think that a better approach in my case should be to use a flat file that contains "name,group" like this:
(Note: Just to clarify that that file is created and accessed in other server but for testing purposes I'm doing it in the /tmp folder for now and I still need it as the source of that data.)

```
john,admins
mike,users
tom,tech
```

and use a custom fact to read those contents so they can be passed to the manifest .pp file I mentioned before and iterate from there.

My problem again is that custom fact. I tried the below but is not giving me the expected result so I would appreciate some help with the correct code:

```
Facter.add('test') do
  setcode do
    file_data = {}
    if File.exist?("/tmp/new_list.txt")
      Array(File.readlines("/tmp/new_list.txt")) do |file|
        file.each do |line|
          line_data = line.split(',')
          file_data[line_data[0]] = line_data[1]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting a hash so I could iterate in the manifest as stated earlier but it seems I'm having what looks like an array:

```
    {
  "test": [
    "john,admins\n",
    "mike,users\n",
    "tom,tech\n"
  ]
}
```

Since this probably is not the best way to do this, I'm open to better solutions so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my question by applying the recommended approach in  this comment here:
[Using Ruby, Reading a file, containing name/value pairs into a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119781/21250743)

It worked like a charm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a higher-level perspective, the *proper* thing to do would probably be to not do what you describe at all.  Using flat files on your target nodes to direct what resources Puppet will manage has bad code smell.  The data describing how your nodes should be configured ought to reside on the server.  Use facts to convey details of how your nodes are *initially* configured at the start of a run.

Creating facts `name_list` and `group_list` solely for the purpose of building a different fact also has bad code smell.  If you need those independent of `hash_list` then you should build the latter on the Puppet side, as an ordinary class variable, not as a fact.  Otherwise, you should generate *only* `hash_list`.

But inasmuch as you seem most interested in why your code does not work, consider this ...

> ```
>     hash_list = {}
>     Facter.value(:name_list).each do |dir_name|
>       Facter.value(:group_list).each do |group_name|
>         hash_list[dir_name] = group_name
>       end
>     end
> ```

Think it through.  For *each* element `dir_name` of the `name_list` fact, *all* the values of the `group_list` fact are assigned, one after the other, to `hash_list[dir_name]`.  That indeed does have the effect that at the end, the last group is the one assigned to each name.

You don't want to form *all* the pairs of one name and one group.  You want only the pairs of corresponding names and groups.  There are various ways you could achieve that, but the [`Array.zip()`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) method of your arrays is an attractive possibility.  Without deviating too far from the original code, that might be:

```rb
    hash_list = {}
    Facter.value(:name_list).zip(Facter.value(:group_list)).each do |name, group|
      hash_list[name] = group
    end
```

But it would probably be more idiomatic to combine `zip` with [`Array.to_h()`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```rb
    hash_list = Facter.value(:name_list).zip(Facter.value(:group_list)).to_h
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer: That helped me to understand why my hash_list was not working.

The reason I used two custom facts, name_list and group_list, was because I was trying to mimic 
something that was already in place, so there was no solid reason behind.

Those two could be replaced by one whose purpose is to retrieve a flat file from a third server 
created with bash that should include lines with "name, group" each one:

john,admin
mike,users

and so on.

Comment: The thing is that since I didn't know how to iterate through such file in just a custom fact, I tried 
these other inefficient approach.

Basically, I would be interested in a valid solution to avoid mine if you can provide it.

On the other hand, I tried the two options you kindly provided but when running puppet agent I have the below 
error for both options:

Error: Facter: Error while resolving custom fact fact='hash_list', resolution='<anonymous>': undefined method `zip' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Questioneer, `undefined method 'zip' for nil:NilClass` suggests that `Facter.value(:name_list)` is evaluating to `nil`. That's not consistent with the results presented in the question, which seem to indicate that in that case, it was evaluating to an array.  I don't know what changed, but I'm not prepared to try to hit a moving target.